# Generate batch number in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, unique

We have a script that should function like so:

Script inserts *n* rows into database inserting the same **unique** number into the *batch* column.

Script puts a job on the AWS queue with the batch number.
AWS worker does some processing and fires off another script on our server.
Script on our server inserts the response from the AWS worker into all rows in the batch.

This is all easy except - creating the batch number.
We can't just get the max batch number and add 1 due to multiple users being able to create a batch at the same time.

So what is the most ideal way to do this? The batch number does not have to be an integer although it could be useful.

Comment: Emulate sequences using additional table with a single autoincrement column?

Comment: I will append some random number to time(), `time() . rand(10,99)`, you can also append some running number to user id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new table called `batches` that has one row per batch.  This table will have an auto-increment column called `batchid`.

Your script will start by inserting a row into this table.  In addition to the `batchid`, it can also contain the time stamp of when the batch was created, who created it, and perhaps other pertinent information.  This id will then be used through the rest of the batch.

Comment: *In addition to the batchid, it can also contain the time stamp of wh...* - That's the first good argument I have heard for having a separate table for the batches I was thinking to do something like insert the first row grab the insert id, insert the remainder of the rows using that id as the batch number, then update the first row to have the batch number.