# Generate batch id in Spring Boot for transactions submitted simultaneously to a MySql database

Tags: mysql, database, spring, spring-boot, database-design

I am building an SMS Gateway in Spring Boot. For instances when multiple SMS messages are submitted at once, I need to generate a batch ID that can be recorded against each SMS message in the mysql database. This ID would be similar for the messages that are submitted concurrently by an individual user.

Any pointers on how to generate such a batch ID in Spring Boot would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything first? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes, thanks. i created another table with an autoincrement ID. Whenever an SMS message or multiple SMS messages were sent, a new row was entered in this table, and its ID was linked to the bulk_id field in the SMS messages table. for reference, i used this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20754610/4623619

Comment: show us exactly what you did here otherwise don't expect us to help.

Comment: yes ive figured out the solution, thanks.